# c++ string can't accept new chars if not defined a minimum

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm aware that the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string s;
s[0] = 'a';
s[1] = 'b';
}
```

says "string subscript out of range" even though std::string's size is 28 bytes. From previous posts, I read to dynamically make the string bigger as you need. What's the best way to do that?
I did the following but it's too ugly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    char c;
    unsigned x = 0;
    std::cout << "char to append: "; s += " "; // what to do here
    std::cin >> c;
    s[x++] = c; //for future appends, x is already 1 position to the right
    std::cout << s;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: using `s[i]` assumes the string is large enough to hold `i`. Use `s += 'a'`

Comment: yeah, but sometimes I want to use s[i] in like 3 positions to the right the index I decide at run time

Comment: Please learn to use the documentation. It's there to help you.

Comment: You may find `std::ostringstream` helpful to you. Docs for  `ostringstream`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream And no. It's not an Irish `stringstream`

Comment: Understand now?

Comment: yes ty for the references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resizing a `std::string`

```
std::string str;
str.resize(2);
str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
```

The `std::string` is basically a container of bytes. It has a "length/size" attribute which can be accessed with the `length()` and `size()` [methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). You can modify this field and ask for a larger memory buffer by calling the `resize()` method.

## Appending to a `std::string`

If you'd like to append to an `std::string`, the cleanest way is by using the `std::ostringstream`, as mentioned in another answer. `std::push_back()` was also discussed. Another way is by using the `std::string`'s `operator+` and `operator+=`. Both take a std::string or char.

```
std::string str;
str += 'a';
str = str + "b";
```

These methods automatically resize as well as append to the `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

> says "string subscript out of range" even though std::string's size is 28 bytes

No, the logical size of this string is "zero characters".

The bytes making up the container itself are irrelevant.

If you want to add characters, use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) or [the `+=` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D):

```
s.push_back('a');
s += 'b';
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of the string object does not indicate the nominal length of the string. Twenty-eight bytes is just the amount of memory that the implementation uses. On a different system it might be more or less.

The way you allocated the string, its length is zero. To expand it, use `push_back`.  You can also initialize it with "ab".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cout << s.length() << '\n';
    s.push_back('a'); // not s[0] = 'a';
    s.push_back ('b'); // not s[1] = 'b';
    std::cout << s.length() << '\n';
    // or initialize it with 'ab'...
    std::string s2 {"ab"};
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

There are a couple of dozen [member-functions of std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that you should familiarize yourself with. `resize()` is one of them.

Comment: if I want to specify the size (in characters) of a string at run time, should I look for resize, reserve, what standard function does that?

Comment: @Powereleven: You have been handed links to some good documentation. Read it before proceeding. Also your C++ book surely covers this topic in detail?

Comment: @Powereleven - There are a couple of dozen member-functions of std::string that you should familiarize yourself with.  
 `resize()` is one of them. 
 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 1):

EDITED
You might want to use the fact that string can behave as a `vector<char>` in some way, so adding a character to the end of the string could be implemented as `s.push_back(c)`, and deleting the last character could also be implemented as `s.pop_back()`.